# Update whole MongoDB Document using DocumentID

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I trying to do CRUD operations in MEAN. I am trying to update a whole document using the documentid. I am not sure how to do this. Below is my code:

```
Users.prototype.updateUser = function (req, cbk) {
    var self = this;
    var reqObj = req.body;
    var response = {
        status: false,
        err: null,
        data: null
    };
    console.log(new Date() + " | user update ", reqObj)
    self.db.collection('users').update({_id:ObjectId(reqObj._id)}, {upsert:true}, function (err, result) {
        if (!err && result.length > 0) {
            response['status'] = true;
            response['data'] = result;
            cbk(response)
        } else {
            response['err'] = 'No user found!';
            cbk(response)
        }
    });
};
```

The JSON Request I am trying to send is:

```
{
    "_id": "59d5db3c4c46e83a14b94617",
    "name": "hello",
    "ind": "0"
}
```

I always get a user not found response. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

EDIT:

Here is JSON Response for list of users:

```
{
    "status": true,
    "err": null,
    "data": [
        {
            "_id": "59d5db344c46e83a14b94616",
            "name": "test"
        },
        {
            "_id": "59d5db3c4c46e83a14b94617",
            "name": "hello"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From documentation you are missing the update object.

> `collection.update(criteria, update[[, options], callback]);`

```
self.db.collection('users')
  .update( { _id: ObjectId(reqObj._id) }, reqObj, { upsert: true },
  function (err, result) {
     if (err) { response['err'] = err.message; }
     else {
       response['status'] = true;
       response['data'] = result;
     }
     cbk(response);
  },
);
```

And if you do not have the object, it will create a new document.

Comment: I changed it as you said. But still getting user not found. Please check my edited question. I am sending the correct document id.

Comment: Refactored  a bit the code, it will be easier to debug now, you should get the proper user or a good error message for you to debug

Comment: `{
    "status": false,
    "err": "The _id field cannot be changed from {_id: ObjectId('59d5db3c4c46e83a14b94617')} to {_id: \"59d5db3c4c46e83a14b94617\"}.",
    "data": null
}` its trying to update the id as well.

Comment: I have made changes to pass the _id as params in the put request. Is there a more standard way or is this fine?

Comment: I think it's fine, I also use it in this manner, with id as param and the rest in body.